# How to accept json data though post in spring boot rest

Tags: json, api, rest, post, spring-boot-actuator

PostMapping method

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/validate")
public class Validatesimapi {
    @PostMapping
    public Simoffers validateSim(@RequestBody ???)
}
```

I want to pass following json object through post request and accept it in validateSim. What should I write at ???.
{
"id": "1234",
"num":"2343335"
}

both the datatypes of id and num is String.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s as simple as adding a DTO with the fields that you want. The Jackson mapper will map the json to that object.

Comment: My DTO has other fields also but I want to accept only two of those fieds id and num for validation purpose.

Comment: @Anonymous then you need to make another DTO that is actually the DTO you require for this endpoint. You could let your more complete DTO inherit from that if you don’t want to duplicate those fields.

Comment: Okk thanks. Is there any other option?

Comment: @Anonymous what do you feel is wrong with this option? It’s a pretty typical way of doing it. The other option is using a map, but then you definitely are duplicating the field names into String keys somewhere too, and as soon as you have multiple types of fields you lose type safety too.

Comment: Can I accept as an original DTO but with only two fields populated that I want i.e. id and num as you mentioned earlier?

Comment: @Anonymous you could just use that object and ignore whatever is in the other fields on this endpoint, at a tiny cost of performance because the json is mapped into those fields. I assume you do have other endpoints where you DO want those fields mapped from json. Otherwise you could just mark them with the `@JsonIgnore` annotation.